# Magento2 Compress js & CSS

Tags: magento2

Magento2 - In order to increase the speed of the site I need to Compress the CSS & JS. I scanned my site using gtmetrix it says I need to Compress CSS & Js.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

using magento 2 cli:

```
bin/magento config:set dev/css/merge_css_files 1
bin/magento config:set dev/css/minify_files 1
bin/magento config:set dev/js/minify_files 1
bin/magento config:set dev/static/sign 1
bin/magento config:set dev/js/merge_files 1
bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
```

also check that `gzip` is working.

Answer (score 0):

To Compress js & CSS and Optimize Magento store, Check this link: https://www.mageplaza.com/blog/magento-2-performance-optimization/

Link contains steps with detail information to Merge CSS and JS Files, Content Delivery Network, Enable Compression and other steps to improve site performance.

Hope this helps!